# Search key replace value

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array:

```
$myArray = array('alfa' => 'apple', 'bravo' => 'banana', 'charlie' => 'cherry', 'delta' => 'danjou pear');
```

I want to search it for certain keys and if found replace the values of those according to this other array:

```
$myReplacements = array('bravo' => 'bolognese', 'lie' => 'candy');
```

I know I can do this:

```
function array_search_replace($haystack, $replacements, $exactMatch = false) {
    foreach($haystack as $haystackKey => $haystackValue) {
        foreach($replacements as $replacementKey => $replacementValue) {
            if($haystackKey == $replacementKey || (!$exactMatch && strpos($haystackKey, $replacementKey) !== false)) {
                $haystack[$haystackKey] = $replacementValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

But, is there really no smarter/faster way to do it?

EDIT: I also need to be able to search for keyparts, so that 'lie' and 'charlie' results in a match.

EDIT2: Expected results are:

```
var_dump(array_search_replace($myArray, $myReplacements));

array(4) { ["alfa"]=> string(5) "apple" ["bravo"]=> string(9) "bolognese" ["charlie"]=> string(5) "candy" ["delta"]=> string(11) "danjou pear" }

var_dump(array_search_replace($myArray, $myReplacements, true));

array(4) { ["alfa"]=> string(5) "apple" ["bravo"]=> string(9) "bolognese" ["charlie"]=> string(6) "cherry" ["delta"]=> string(11) "danjou pear" }
```

Comment: Take a look at the array_merge() function as you're using string keys - it has a very particular behaviour that should vastly simplify what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks, in my case it's important though, that no new keys (elements) from $myReplacements are added to $myArray. If an element in $myReplacements is not found in $myArray, then do NOT add it to $myArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in PHP are hashes, you don't need to search for a key, you can access it in O(1) time.

```
$myArray = array('alfa' => 'apple', 'bravo' => 'banana', 'charlie' => 'cherry', 'delta' => 'danjou pear');
$myReplacements = array('bravo' => 'bolognese', 'lie' => 'candy');

var_dump($myArray);

foreach($myReplacements as $k => $v) {
  if(array_key_exists($k, $myArray)) {
    $myArray[$k] = $v;
  }
}

var_dump($myArray);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["alfa"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["bravo"]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  ["charlie"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
  ["delta"]=>
  string(11) "danjou pear"
}
array(4) {
  ["alfa"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["bravo"]=>
  string(9) "bolognese"
  ["charlie"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
  ["delta"]=>
  string(11) "danjou pear"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good!
Only one problem: Sometimes I need to check if a key in $myReplacement is part of the key in $myArray. I want 'lie' and 'charlie' to be a match.

Comment: If you want partial key matches, then your nested foreach loops are probably the best way.  You could optimize your function to use my code if `$exactMatch` is true to speed it up in those cases, and only use the nested foreach if you need a partial match.

Comment: Good, I will modify my code to use this splendid array_key_exists thing! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP's [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) function.

Also, [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) does something similar.

In your code:

```
$finalArray = array_replace($myArray, $myReplacements);
```

#### Full PHP Code

```
<?php
    $myArray = array('alfa' => 'apple', 'bravo' => 'banana', 'charlie' => 'cherry', 'delta' => 'danjou pear');
    $myReplacements = array('bravo' => 'bolognese', 'lie' => 'candy');
    $finalArray = array_replace($myArray, $myReplacements);
    print_r($finalArray);
?>
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [alfa] => apple
    [bravo] => bolognese
    [charlie] => cherry
    [delta] => danjou pear
    [lie] => candy
)
```

#### Fiddle here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/60o5xT

Comment: Thanks, but this also adds elements from $myReplacements to $myArray, which I need to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
<?php
$myArray = array('alfa' => 'apple', 'bravo' => 'banana', 'charlie' => 'cherry', 'delta' => 'danjou pear');
$myReplacements = array('bravo' => 'bolognese', 'lie' => 'candy');
print_r(array_merge($myArray, $myReplacements));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [alfa] => apple
    [bravo] => bolognese
    [charlie] => cherry
    [delta] => danjou pear
    [lie] => candy
)
```

Using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Can you post your code in your answer? It's nicer if people can see it immediately.

Comment: Thanks, but no, it adds 'lie' => candy to $myArray, which must be avoided. Size and keys of $myArray must stay unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to directly replace the matching key

```
<?php
$base = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$replacements = array(0 => "pineapple", 4 => "cherry");
$replacements2 = array(0 => "grape");

$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements, $replacements2);
print_r($basket);
?>
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => grape
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
    [4] => cherry
)
```

Comment: No, size and keys of $base must not be changed.